# Sophos is blocking my site - how do I remove it from their list?

Tags: web-development, malware, virus, blacklist

I've had a call from a client who says a visitor cannot access their site as a virus protection program called Sophos is blocking it, saying it will steal information.

I've scanned the site with Succuri and a couple of similar sites for malware but it seems fine.

I've checked the Sophos site and couldnt find any where to remove it from their blacklist.

Has anyone experienced this before?

The site is [here](http://austin7.org.au/) if anyone wants to take a look.

Answer (score 7):

From the Sophos [KB](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/119440.aspx)

> If you believe that the URL has been blocked on the basis of hosting malware, but you think this is a false positive, go to the reassessment request form: https://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/reassessment-request.aspx to submit a request to Sophos to reassess the site. Ensure that you complete all the fields.
>
> If you are not a Sophos customer, (i.e. someone else has informed you that Sophos has blocked your site) please try and find out which Sophos product was alerting on the site, as this will allow us to investigate your query more quickly. If you really cannot get this information, please enter a best guess in the mandatory field 'Product'. (Sophos Anti-Virus comes under the heading of 'Endpoint Security and Control'.)